# Trying to iterate over a activerecord to fetch the values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying iterate through following active record

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<WantedEquipment id: 1, identifier: "WEID-0000001", title: "Wanted a Test Equipment", category_id: 1, sub_category_id: 3, listing_type: nil, description: "This is a test wanted equipment.", name: "John", email: "john.user@mailinator.com", user_id: nil, status: 1, created_at: "2017-02-25 16:10:35", updated_at: "2017-02-25 16:10:35">, #<WantedEquipment id: 2, identifier: "WEID-0000002", title: "Wanted a Test Equipment1", category_id: 1, sub_category_id: 3, listing_type: nil, description: "This is a test wanted equipment.", name: "John", email: "john.user@mailinator.com", user_id: nil, status: 1, created_at: "2017-02-25 16:10:50", updated_at: "2017-02-25 16:10:50">]>
```

To collect the values of column email. I am quiet new to ruby. 
I ran the following on rails console.

```
WantedEquipment.all.each do |eq|
     eq.email
end
```

As a result I got the whole table again instead of just the emails. Could somebody please guide me here?

Answer (score 8):

If all you need are the email addresses and not the actual AR objects, then use this:

```
WantedEquipment.pluck(:email)
```

This will translate into the following SQL:

```
SELECT "wanted_equipments"."email" FROM "wanted_equipments"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select all email using following way

```
WantedEquipment.select('email')
```

If possible always use database level memory instead of system.

Comment: Unlike `pluck` this will still instantiate `WantedEquipment` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either select or pluck here.

```
WantedEquipment.pluck(:email)
```

Or

```
WantedEquipment.select(:email)
```

Depends upon your result set `performance` you can use anyone.